# Interrupt download (recv) of a file through socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

In an application I'm currently working on, I need to stop downloading some file if I realize it's not what I'm looking for. The protocol doesn't provide any way to know it before I start receiving the file (like headers or so).

As an example, in some cases I might be looking for a file of exactly X bytes in size, but after I have downloaded X bytes and I keep getting more bytes, this is not the file I'm looking for as its size is greater than X. In this case, I want to stop downloading to free network bandwidth resources. The protocol doesn't provide any way to notify the server about this.

I read somewhere that `close(fd)` or `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)` won't actually stop downloading as the server will continue to `send()` the file and this will continue to consume network bandwidth. I am also not sure about if I just stop calling `recv()` and packets still arrive, will they fill the buffer and then start to be discarded?  If it matters, the protocol used is based on TCP (but I would like some solution that can also be used for UDP based protocols).

I became even more doubtful that stopping calls to `recv()` would solve it, after I searched for programmatic bandwidth control (`sleep()`, token bucket..) as an alternative solution (reduce download speed to about zero after I realize it's not the file I'm looking for). How can I control network bandwidth usage by reducing `recv()` calls if the server will still be `send()`ing? I didn't catch it.

Main idea is to entirely stop the download.

What would you suggest?

Comment: TCP is a connection based protocol, so basically if you close the connection the server will stop sending eventually.

Comment: What makes you think that server will continue to send the packets ? At the worst case scenario, when you closed the client socket your server will get a socket error while sending, and stop sending data. You are worrying too much about details for such a basic requirement.

Comment: Also , never think about using UDP for sending a file. UDP is unreliable meaning you don't even get a response about the packet arrived the destination or not. It's not an option.

Comment: I've mentioned UDP because of protocols like QUIC and some other used for streaming...

Comment: It can be used for streaming because streaming does not need reliable connection. Think about a live Tv Show. If a few packets are lost, not a problem at all, you just see some defects. But if even a single packet is lost in a file transfer, the file will be corrupt.

Comment: What if my application is receiving a video streaming and it notices that it is already stored on disk and want to stop uselessly receiving that video. Wouldn't it be possible because it's UDP based?

Comment: Not easy to answer, because if you use UDP to transfer that file, you will have no mechanism to detect if something went wrong or not. So "unnecessarily" becomes out of context, you have no choice to continue the transfer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read somewhere that `close(fd)` or `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD`) won't actually stop download as server will continue to `send()` file and this will continue to consume network bandwidth.

If you `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)` your own `recv()` will unblock with a return code of zero, which will cause the code to close the socket, which will cause the localhost to issue an RST if any more data comes from the peer, which will cause an ECONNRESET at the sender (after a few more `send()` calls, not necessarily immediately).

Where did you read this nonsense?

> I became even more doubtful about if stop calling `recv()` would solve it

It won't solve it, but it will eventually stop the sender from sending, because of TCP flow control. It isn't a solution to this problem.

Comment: That's nice. I don't know TCP so deeply. Thanks. About that nonsense: maybe it was about UDP and I didn't noticed...

Comment: About TCP Flow Control: that means that if I slow down transfer speed (by reducing `recv()` calls with `sleep()`) too much, is there a risk of connection get closed? Or does this applies only to entirely stop calling `recv()`?

Comment: If you receive slower than the sender is sending, the sender will eventually get blocked if he's in blocking mode, or EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK if he's in non-blocking mode. That includes the case of not receiving at all.